# wallpaper app doesn't show images from firebase

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm making a wallpaper app and I'm trying to make category section with a category text over a wallpaper representing the category (Like Text - nature, picture - forest). The problem is, that nothing shows up when I play the app, but there is no errors as well, everything should be working fine, but it doesnt.

Firebase rules are all set up.

I've granted access to the internet for the app.

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.+'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
}
```

Category fragment class:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    //Firebase
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference categoryBackground;

    //FirebaseUI adapteris
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<CategoryItem> options;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryItem, CategoryViewHolder> adapter;
    //view
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    private static CategoryFragment INSTANCE = null;

    public CategoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        categoryBackground = database.getReference(Common.STR_CATEGORY_BACKGROUND);


        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategoryItem>()
                .setQuery(categoryBackground,CategoryItem.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryItem, CategoryViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final CategoryItem model) {

                Picasso.get()
                        .load(model.getImageLink())
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .into(holder.background_image, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Exception e) {
                                //Bandyti dar karta online jeigu nepavyksta
                                Picasso.get()
                                        .load(model.getImageLink())
                                        .error(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                                        .into(holder.background_image, new Callback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess() {

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError(Exception e) {
                                                Log.e("ERROR_", "Couldn't fetch image");
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });

                holder.category_name.setText(model.getName());

                holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                    }
                });
            }


            @Override
            public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_category_item, parent, false);
                return new CategoryViewHolder(itemView);
            }
        };
    }


    public static CategoryFragment getInstance()
    {

        if(INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new CategoryFragment();
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_category);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager((gridLayoutManager));

        setCategory();

        return view;

    }

    private void setCategory() {
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.stopListening();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, I was sitting hours on this and didn't notice a spelling mistake in a string. Kill me.